# node doesnt run in intergreted terminal in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed node js . it works in Powershell , cmd but not in vs code .

```
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node -v
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I installed node while vscode was already running.

Try reloading vscode. This issue on github gave me more clarity:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13671#issuecomment-255778379